Error in file sigslot.h when building WebRTC version M120
I am building WebRTC using version M120 with the command:
gn gen out/clang/win_x64 --args="target_os="win" target_cpu="x64" is_component_build=false is_clang=true is_debug=false rtc_use_h264=true ffmpeg_branding="Chrome" rtc_include_tests=false rtc_build_examples=false use_custom_libcxx=true" --ide=vs2022.
However, I am encountering errors in the file sigslot.h. Is there a way to resolve this issue? Thank you.
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '...'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '...'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2182: 'Args': this use of 'void' is not valid
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2365: 'Args': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base/third_party/sigslot/sigslot.h(327): error C2365: 'Args': redefinition; previous definition was 'template parameter'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base/third_party/sigslot/sigslot.h(327): note: see declaration of 'Args'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2059: syntax error: '...'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2059: syntax error: ')'
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body
D:\codes\webrtc\webrtc-build-120\src\rtc_base\third_party\sigslot\sigslot.h:327: error: C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition

